# Dictionary named after variable value

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a dictionary based on a variable. I want to name the dictionary based on the value of the variable. What ends up happening is that the dictionary is called username (the name of the variable) instead of the value of the variable. Does anyone know how to do this?

This is the code:

```
username = input("username:")

username = {}﻿
```

Comment: what's your expected output?

Comment: Don't do these *assign/call* by name things, it is very bad design to begin with.

Comment: So if the user enters "test", you want the dictionary to be named "test"? Dynamically creating variables is rarely, if ever the right approach.

Comment: Probably you want https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/3001761

Comment: I dont really care if it is the right approach, just wondering if it is possible to dynamicly create dictionaries based on variables values Carcigenicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)